# Hook when switching between blogs in WordPress multisite?

Tags: hook, wordpress, transient, multisite

Is there a hook for WordPress multisite that I can use when a user switches between blogs in the Dashboard?

I need to clear some transients when the user is logged in the Dashboard, but only if she switched from one blog to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hookr is your friend.

```
    /**
     * Fires when the blog is switched.
     *
     * @since MU
     *
     * @param int $new_blog New blog ID.
     * @param int $new_blog Blog ID.
     */
    do_action( 'switch_blog', $new_blog, $new_blog );
```

http://hookr.io/3.9.1/actions/do_action/switch_blog/